# Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project

Tags: .net, deployment, bootstrapper, prerequisites

I have a Visual Studio Setup project and have followed the steps mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553794/can-a-net-word-2003-add-in-be-installed-outside-of-the-gac/553886#553886) to load the Shared Add-in Support Update for the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 (KB908002) to the prerequisites list. The entry appears but there is this following warning shown

*No 'HomeSite' attribute has been provided for 'Shared Add-in Support Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 (KB908002)', so the package will be published to the same location as the bootstrapper.*

I use the Download component from the component vendor's website option. How do I set a homesite for this update so that the update is directly downloaded and installed. I do not want to distribute the update along with my setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the setup bootstrapper being able to download and install the files included in the KB908002 patch you would have to specify a `HomeSite` attribute for each of the files in the package description for the bootstrapper. This package description is contained in an XML file named *package.xml* in the following location (where *v6.0A* is the version of the SDK):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper
    \Packages\KB908002\package.xml
```

The description lists the files included in the patch within the `PackageFiles` element. Each of the `PackageFile` elements can now have a `HomeSite` attribute specifying a download URL. However, as far as I know, Microsoft doesn't offer these files as an individual download, so you would have to host them on your own.

```
<PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
  <PackageFile Name="lockbackRegKey.msi" 
               HomeSite="http://myserver.com/lockbackRegKey.msi" /> 
  <PackageFile Name="extensibilityMSM.msi" 
               HomeSite="http://myserver.com/extensibilityMSM.msi" /> 
  <PackageFile Name="office2003-kb907417sfxcab-ENU.exe" 
               HomeSite="http://myserver.com/office2003-kb907417sfxcab-ENU.exe" /> 
  <PackageFile Name="VerifPrequisites.exe" 
               HomeSite="http://myserver.com/VerifPrequisites.exe" /> 
</PackageFiles>
```

Another option would be to distribute the files along with your setup - you can still distribute a single package. Just use a tool like IExpress (included with Windows) to generate a self-extracting package containing the patch, the MSI and the setup.exe bootstrapper (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535966?sort=votes)).