# Making Excel 2002 use .NET v2.0.50727 runtime

Tags: .net, excel, excel-2002

Good morning,

I have a .Net 2.0 runtime DLL that I am trying to load from Excel (it's correct regasm'd).  I've verified with the Fusion Log Viewer that it is trying to load with the 1.1 runtime instead o 2.0, which explains why it's failing.

One solution is to put an EXCEL.EXE.config file next to excel that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
    <startup>
     <requiredRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

However, I do not have admninistrative priviledges on the machine.  What are my alternatives to Make Excel 2002 use the 2.0 runtime instead of 1.1?

Regards,
Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you encounter is a bug in both Office XP and 2003. For a fix, you basically have to install the [**KB908002**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908002) update from Microsoft.

See my answers to the following questions:

- [Can a .NET Word 2003 add-in be installed outside of the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553794/can-a-net-word-2003-add-in-be-installed-outside-of-the-gac/553839)
- [.NET app.config question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436958/-net-app-config-question)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  I'm getting some generic Office install warning message, but soon enough I'm hoping to give the patch a try.  Voted you up in the meantime, but will not forget to check the accepted answer icon if it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to rename/remove this registry entry: ([Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/2ca664bc-c280-492c-b240-ae06f776803d/))

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\AppPatch\v2.0.50727.00000\excel.exe
```

Comment: Note that with .NET framework 4.0 you'll need to find the registry key for V4.0 as well.