# shim add-in not loaded

Tags: c#, .net

I am kind of new on the whole shim add-in thing so go easy on me.

Here is what I did:

1) create shared add-in (new_addin) and put messagebox on the on connect proc

2) add shim add-in project and chose for word and excel

3) then add setup project add primary output for the three project set the register property for the shim vsdrpCOM and for the add-in and the ManagedAggregator to vsdrpDoNotRegister and  it work fine on my computer.

But when i install it on other computers have the .net freamwork 2 it give not loaded. A run time error occurred the load behavior changed from 3 to 2 and i put `try` `catch` in the add-in startup completed  but it didn't through any error.

Answer (score 0):

Is KB908002 installed? Please see my answer to this question:

> [**Making Excel 2002 use .NET v2.0.50727 runtime**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666592/making-excel-2002-use-net-v2-0-50727-runtime)