# Unable to load the Excel 2003 Add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I'm trying to develop an Excel 2003 Add-in using Visual Studio 2008 (SP1).I didn't add any code expect for the boilerplate code added by Visual Studio.

When I run the application in VS it loads up Excel, but the add-in itself does not work. The "COM Add-Ins" window list the add-in, but it's unchecked. The "Load Behavior" reads as "Not loaded.A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in".
VS was unable to catch the exception at load-time even though I've enabled all options under Debug > Exceptions.

I also tried setting up VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS Environmental variable as mentioned in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003.aspx).Surprisingly that also didn't show me any messages.

I'm running Office 2003 (SP3) under Windows XP.It'll be great if someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I underestimated the power of Re-install !!! I removed and installed Visual Studio Tools for Office again. And voila all started working again as if nothing has ever happened. 
:-)

Comment: For a VS 2008 solution see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to install [**KB908002**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908002). Please see

> - [.NET app.config question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436958/-net-app-config-question)
> - [How to select .NET framework version running from Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790580/how-to-select-net-framework-version-running-from-excel)

The installation with VS 2008 is a little more complicated. See here:

> [Can a .NET Word 2003 add-in be installed outside of the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553794/can-a-net-word-2003-add-in-be-installed-outside-of-the-gac/553886#553886)

Comment: Thanks Divo. But the patch mentioned is specific to VS 2005. I did try installing it, but it said unable to find VS 2005.