# VBA C# DLL no registration

Tags: c#, vba, dll

I have made a C# .NET dll which i would like to run from VBA without register it.
I've found the solution [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333819) and it works perfectly, but only when the assembly is made with the Framework NET 3.5 or older. 
With Framework 4.0, i'm getting the error "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded"..
Someone could help me please?

Comment: Oh dear, that is not a helpful answer.  It uses a .NET 1.0 technique, one that did not yet permit determining what CLR version to load.  Selecting the tlb files from the v4.0.30319 folder accomplishes nothing.  That it works for a 3.5 assembly is an accident, a common one today since most machines don't have a .NET 1.x version installed anymore.  Woe be you if it does.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, i've found the solution.

By default, Excel uses the 1.1 framework as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/790589/3909712).
If you have a look into the Windows Registry,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Policy\AppPatch\YOUR_FRAMEWORK_VERSION\excel.exe\
```

you can see the targeted version is v1.1.....
So, the solution is to make an Excel.exe.config file that forces Framework version 4, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473272/3909712)

```
 <configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```